# Exact frequency of a specific word in a single cell (excluding suffix and prefix)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I earlier worked out a good solution for this with the help of the comunity, it works really good but I found out it can only handle suffix words (it dosen't ignore prefix-words).

Formula:

```
=IF(B1<>"";(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1;B1&" ";"")))/(LEN(B1)+1)+IF(RIGHT(A1;LEN(B1))=B1;1;0);"")
```

**A** contains sentences, multiple words (without punctuation)
**B** contains the word I want to count the exact frequency of.
**C** here is there the formula is placed and where I get the result

Sample table:

```
|              A            |  B   |     C    |
|:-------------------------:|:----:|:--------:|
| boots                     | shoe |     0    |
----------------------------------------------|
| shoe                      | shoe |     1    |
----------------------------------------------|
| shoes                     | shoe |     0    |
----------------------------------------------|
| ladyshoe dogshoe catshoe  | shoe |     3    |
----------------------------------------------|
```

In C-column I am getting correct output in row 1, 2 and 3 *but not 4*. I want C4 should return `0` and not `3`.

The problem is that it makes no match for `shoexxxxxxxxxxx` (correct) but makes a match for `xxxxxxxxxxxshoe` (wrong).

I only want the formula to count the exact match for `shoe`, any other word should not be counted for.

Comment: What happens if you replace RIGHT by LEFT in your formula ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this formula:

```
=IF(B1<>"",(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," "&B1&" ","")))/(LEN(B1)+2),"")+IF(A1=B1,1,0)+IF(LEFT(A1,LEN(B1)+1)=B1&" ",1,0)+IF(RIGHT(A1,LEN(B1)+1)=" "&B1,1,0)
```

I'll denote a space by `*` to make the following clearer:

There are four cases to consider:

1. `string`; the word has no spaces on either side (and is therefore the only word in cell `A1`
2. `string*`; the word appears at the start of a list of words.
3. `*string`; the word appears at the end of a list of words.
4. `*string*`; the word is in the middle of a list of words.

First we count the number of occurrences of `*string*`, by substituting `"*string*"` for `""`, subtracting the length of the new string from the old one, and dividing by `len(string)+2` (which is the length of `*string*`).

Then we add one more to our count if `A1` is exactly `string`, with no spaces either side.

Then we add one more if `A1` starts with `string*`, and one more if `A1` ends with `*string`.